# Printing a Google Chart: print css ignored

Tags: css, google-visualization

I have a Google horizontal bar chart that grows downwards dynamically depending on the number of items, up to 2500 px.

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="pagecontent">
        <div id="chart" style="width:80%; height: ${chartHeight}px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to fit it to one full page when printing. None of the browsers seems to care about the width/height I set, no matter what combination of min-height, max-height and height I tried. Tried setting both 100% and a pixel value, but the 2500px chart always ends up one and a half page tall.

```
div.page {
    page-break-after: always;
}

.pagecontent
{
    margin: 40px 5px 5px 5px;
}

@media print {
    body {font-size: xx-small;}
    #chart {width: 100% !important; min-height:100px !important ;max-height:100px !important; height:100px !important;}
    div.pagecontent {margin: 5px;}
}
```

Fitting the height is the lesser issue, the problem is that half of the chart is missing because of being too wide.

Comment: Print-related issues are often browser-specific.  Can you please specify browser and version? I know you say "None of the browsers," but it helps to know which ones you're testing.

Comment: Chrome 44.0.2403.157, IE 11.0.9600.17937. Didn't work in Firefox yesterday, but today I updated to the latest and their multi-page print stopped working entirely so cannot test.

Comment: Is your goal to shrink the chart, or truncate it before it goes multiple pages?

Comment: Nevermind.  I see width is your issue. Interesting. I've done some CSS media queries, but never applied to Google Charts. The charts render as SVG, and SVG doesn't always behave the same way when styled with CSS as HTML does. Maybe try rendering as PNG and printing that? Link to follow.

Comment: I'd like to shrink it to fit one page, if possible, but the most important is to shrink horizontally so the full horizontal axis is visible. Now the width seems to depend on the browser window size: if I print from a 16:9 monitor, half of the width is missing, if I use the 4:3 monitor, about 80% of the chart's width is visible in print preview.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

Comment: Interesting. Will let you know how it goes soon.

Comment: The `chart.getImageURI()` method returns a base-64 encoded PNG string. I've seen people put that straight in a link before to open it as it's own document.  If all you want to print is the chart, maybe you could even set it as the URL for for a alternate print document in meta tags.  Haven't done that in like 15 years, but I think that still works.

Comment: It didn't help. The CSS print settings for the PNG are still ignored.

Comment: #chart {display: none !important;}
 #chartpng {display: block !important; height:200px !important; width: 90% !important;}

Comment: The problem seems to be that the generated PNG has the same size as the chart and it seems browsers are refusing to size down images, or I don't know how to make them.

Comment: Grasping for ideas here at this point, but maybe try using a physical unit for the measure instead of a percentage? That or use an alternate print document and render the chart to the correct size for the printer there.

Comment: `<link rel=alternate href="/en/html/print" hreflang=en type=text/html media=print title="English HTML (for printing)">`

Comment: It seems to boil down to the problem of stretching images to full page in print which is not well supported. I have given up and using width: 700px as others suggest. This is acceptable enough on screen and the width is about right in most browsers.